# Count number of distinct lists excluding zeros in two-dimensional array

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

In Excel 2019 I have a formula in a cell which when evaluated with F9 in the formula bar returns the following two-dimensional array (matrix):

```
{0,0; 0,0; 0,0; 0,0; 0,0; 0,0; 44846,1; 44846,1; 44846,1}
```

I'd like to nest this result inside another function which would count the number of distinct lists (pair of values, or rows), without counting the zeros. *Distinct values* means unique values + first occurrences of duplicate values.

So, for the previous 2D array, the formula should return 1, because there's only one unique pair (the `44846,1`), without counting the zeros.

For the following 2D array, the formula should return 2, because there's only two unique pair (the `44843,1` and the `44844,1`), without counting the zeros:

```
{44843,1; 44844,1; 0,0; 0,0; 0,0; 0,0; 0,0; 0,0; 0,0}
```

For the following 2D array, the formula should return 4, because there's only four unique pair (the `44843,1`, the `44843,2`, the `44845,3`, and the `44845,4`), without counting the zeros:

```
{0,0; 0,0; 44843,1; 44843,2; 44845,3; 44845,4; 0,0; 0,0; 0,0}
```

I'd like such formula to not require Excel 365, VBA, and ideally not be an array formula (*i.e.* require <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

If you need more background, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't be sure this won't require CSE, though it should work for all Excel versions:

```
=SUM(
    IF(FREQUENCY(
        IF(MMULT(N(ζ<>0),{1;1}),
            MMULT(
                N(INDEX(ζ,,1)&"|"&INDEX(ζ,,2)=TRANSPOSE(INDEX(ζ,,1)&"|"&INDEX(ζ,,2))),
                ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS(ζ)))
            )
        ),
        ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS(ζ)))),1
    )
)
```

Replace ζ with your array.

Comment: It worked. It does require CSE.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

If in Row:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(A1:C3<>0,MMULT(A1:C3,{1;10^4;10^8})),IF(A1:C3<>0,MMULT(A1:C3,{1;10^4;10^8})))>0))
```

If in Column:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(A1:A10<>0, MMULT((B1:C10<>"")*B1:C10,{1;10^4;10^8})), IF(A1:A10<>0, MMULT((B1:C10<>"")*B1:C10,{1;10^4;10^8})))>0))
```

- Adjust cell references as needed.

Comment: Hi. Could you please explain the code a bit more? In the row version, what is the range A1:C3? How do I know if I need to use the row version or the column version?

Comment: @alejnavab ,,, it's more than a row 3x3 ,,,, otherwise for single row A1:C1,,, depends what U need ☺